# How to expose a web appication via API?

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine

we have create a web application on top of google app engine and python. which is almost about to complete it web front phase. I would also like to make it available almost all part of it to external applications. { via , xml , json , http , as many as possible. } . what's the best way to do it ? any library either for python or django available out ther ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [django-piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) could be of interest for you. But I do not know if there are restrictions for appengine.

Comment: The django-piston-app-engine project claims to be "A fork of django-piston modified to work on Google App Engine," might be worth a shot: http://bitbucket.org/gumptioncom/django-piston-app-engine/

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is no much difference between service for humans and for robots (web-services).

But [restish](http://github.com/ish/restish) -- mini-framework for building RESTful web services can be your choice.